# Storing the buffer of fgets in Array

Tags: c, string, fgets

I'm new to C (coming from Java) and naturally that poses some difficulties. I would like to write just a short program that reads in char-Arrays from stdin and stores the individual strings in an array. After reading in the strings I just want to have them printed out, but that's when it gets really confusing for me.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

char **stringarray[2];
char buffer[5];
int i = 0;
while( i < 2 && fgets(buffer, 5, stdin) != NULL){
    char *tmp = buffer;
    stringarray[i] = &tmp;
    i++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("%s\n", &stringarray[i]);

}

return 0;
}
```

The first part does in fact compiles (i.e. the part before the print out). I understand that my stringArray has to be an array of char pointers, because that's what a char array basically is in c. It's a pointer to the first character. At first I just wrote

```
while( i < 2 && fgets(buffer, 5, stdin) != NULL){
    stringarray[i] = buffer;
    i++;
}
```

which also compiled, but of course then I have one pointer that points to buffer, which will only save the last string that has been read. 
What do I have to do that I can store a simple array of strings?

Comment: You don't need an [array of pointers to pointers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) for this. An array of pointers would be enough.

Comment: In your `printf("%s\n", &stringarray[i])`, you're taking *the address* (&-operator) of the i-th element. That's certainly not what you want.

Comment: Ok, I changed it again, but I still have the problem that I don't know how permanently store what buffer points to during one iteration of the loop.

Comment: the adress-operator was there by accident. Sorry for the extra confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change your code as following.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* to use strdup function */


int main(){

char *stringarray[2]; /* I don't understand why you use pointer to pointer than pointer, char **stringarray[2]; */
char buffer[6]; /* I suggest 6 than 5, because string has terminate byte in C */
int i = 0;
while( i < 2 && fgets(buffer, 5, stdin) != NULL){
    stringarray[i] = strndup(buffer, 5);
    i++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("%s\n", stringarray[i]); /* changed stringarray */

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strndup` is not standard if im not mistaken. It duplicates string (allocates memory and copies the original string into it), in java you don't have to think of memory, but in `C` `stringarray[i] = buffer` is only `address` assignment, meaning all elemnts of `stringarray` will point to the same buffer at the end of the loop

Answer (score 2):

`char **stringarray[2];` is like `char ***stringarray` because an array is like a pointer to the first value of the array.

printf wants a `char*` and `&stringarray[i]` is a `char**`

if a string is an array then **an array of strings is an array of array**.

So the code is :

```
 int main()
{
    char stringarray[2][5];//array of (array of char)
    char buffer[5];
    int i = 0;
    while( i < 2 && fgets(buffer, 5, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(stringarray[i],buffer); //copies the buffer into the string array
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", stringarray[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you didn't want to use `buffer` you could just writte :

```
    while( i < 2 && fgets(stringarray[i], 5, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

Note that you get 5 characters, the last one will be the NUL terminator `\0`. And because you have to press enter to validate, the one before `\0` will be Line Feed`\n`. And you will only have 3 characters you really wanted.

Comment: defenitly no, don't delete. But [arrays are not pointers](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/)

Comment: I can't access to your link :(. I have always thought that arrays allocate a number of variables and kept the pointer to the first. I will do some reseach, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using dynamic allocation technique as below .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int num;
   int len=0;
   int i;
   printf("Enter the number of elements to be entered ");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   //Allocate memory for the array of strings 
   char **var=(char **)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));

   for(i=0;i<num;i++)
   {
      printf("Enter the string   : ");
      //get strings using getline 
      getline(&var[i],&len,stdin); 

   }
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
   {
      printf("String %d   : %s \n",i,var[i]);


   }

    free(var);

}
```